# Regex to match specific, multiline object in JSON list

Tags: json, regex, intellij-idea

I work with JSON lists which can look somewhat like the following:

```
 [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
```

What would be the proper way to write a regex which correctly extracts only the list item which contains the word `$everyone`? I need to extract the entire object, so the correct result should be:

```
   {
     "accessType": "*",
     "principalType": "ROLE",
     "principalId": "$everyone",
     "permission": "DENY"
   }
```

I have tried something like `\{(?s).*everyone(?s).*\}`, but this will match the first and last opening and closing curly bracket in the list, with everything in between.

Comment: Have you tried `.*?` instead of `.*`?

Comment: Can't you parse the JSON instead? Concerning the regex, try with `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: @sp00m I can't do it in code unfortunately - this regex needs to be plugged into the search feature of my IDE (IDEA) in order to perform multiline search-and-replace over a large number of files. IDEA unfortunately only supports normal multiline find-and-replace for single files.

Comment: `\{(?s).*?everyone(?s).*?\}` *almost* works, in the sense that it stops the search at the first `}` encountered after `everyone` is found. Now I only need it to also start at the first `{` before that.

Comment: Perhaps you should try with xpath for json: http://www.defiantjs.com/ See section `XPath Evaluator`.

Comment: If it's one-off task: `\{[^}]*?everyone[^}]*\}`

Comment: @nhahtdh - this works perfectly, thank you very much indeed! If you want, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Perhaps, this is better: `\{[^}]*?\\$everyone[^}]*}`, as `$` should be there, right? *`\\$ Escapes $.`* (see [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-off task of search and replace in IDE:

```
\{[^}]*?everyone[^}]*\}
```

If you need the `$`, use either:

```
\{[^}]*?\$everyone[^}]*\}
\{[^}]*?[$]everyone[^}]*\}
```

Instead of `(?s).*` which allows anything in between `{` and `everyone` and between `everyone` and `}`, I restrict it to `[^}]*?`, which disallows `}` in the "free" part.

A lot of assumptions is made in the regex, so don't use it in general case.