# Regex to match specific key in a JSON list

Tags: regex, sed

I work with Json looks something like below

```
[
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "everyone",
      "permission": "Allow"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
```

I would like to change the access type to "restricted" instead of "*" for the PrincipalID: "everyone"...
I am using something like `sed '\{[^}]*?everyone[^}]*\},s,"accessType": "*","accessType": "Restricted",' sdcard/etc/sample.json` but it doesnt work. it has to look like below:

```
{
      "accessType": "Restricted",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "everyone",
      "permission": "Allow"
    },
```

it is a continuation to the previous question:
[Regex to match specific, multiline object in JSON list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200466/regex-to-match-specific-multiline-object-in-json-list)

I cannot use any 3rd party applications to perform this action, only using sed and regex or any 1 liner unix command

Comment: You should generally _not_ try to use regex to parse JSON.  Use the right tool for the job (probably not Sed).  Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON parser for this, like `jq`.

I put your json in a file (called `jsonfile` below) and can obtain your desired result like

```
$ cat jsonfile | jq. '.[0]'.   // OR jq '.[0]' jsonfile
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "everyone",
  "permission": "Allow"
}
// also works for .[1] and .[2]
```

Now I **adjust** the right json field like this:

```
$ jq '.[].accessType = "Restricted"' jsonfile
[
  {
    "accessType": "Restricted",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "accessType": "Restricted",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "everyone",
    "permission": "Allow"
  },
  {
    "accessType": "Restricted",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW"
  }
]
```

and I can grep the first JSON list with a pipe:

```
$ jq '.[].accessType = "Restricted"' jsonfile | jq '.[0]'
{
  "accessType": "Restricted",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
  "permission": "DENY"
}
```

Comment: A small improvement would be to use one `jq` command (which I think should be possible),  but `jq '.[0] | fromjson | .[].accessType = "Restricted"' jsonfile'` gives an error that `only strings can be parsed`... Working on it

Answer (score 1):

sed is not the right tool for the job. Use `jq`, a JSON-aware tool that can parse JSON even if its formatting changes.

```
jq '.[] |= (if .principalId == "everyone"
            then (.accessType |= "restricted")
            else . end)' \
    file.json
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are sticking to this basic and known JSON structure and assuming SED supports a lot of PCRE syntax then this would work:

```
(\{[^}]+"accessType": ")(\*)(",[^}]+"principalId": "everyone",[^}]+\})
```

https://regex101.com/r/xt6DY9/1/

Comment: This pattern is POSIX ERE compliant, but that means OP must know how to enable it and how to properly quote the sed command.